# Navigating a view with Gyroscopes - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

i'm new to game developing so i might be a little confusing on defining what i need.

Assume i have a wide background picture, much bigger than the screen(e.g.4000*3000px), how should i approach if i want to navigate it with the input from the gyroscopes?
i mean handling the device up, down, left, right and so on.

If you remember the old Mosquitoes game on Symbian i would like to do something similar but without the camera.

However any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Use UIScrollView - put your pic inside the scroll view and try to navigate with fingers.
When scroll will be working nice, use [this](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=151394) or [this](http://mobileorchard.com/how-to-make-an-iphone-app-part-5-the-accelerometer/) or any other tutorial to find out how to use accelerometer.
Finally, when you will be able to collect data from accelerometer, give it to UIScrollView using `[myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:myRect animated:YES];`
All needed math and physics must be done by you.